# How to build a navigation tree?

Tags: node.js

How to build a navigation tree?
Is it possible to solve this within node.js or do I need to use something else?

**Logic.**

- the page starts;
- a tree is being built on the left;
- if the node contains child elements, then the node can be collapsed, expanded;

The menu data source is MySQL database.

**In the future it is planned:**

- the user clicks on the menu;
- an article corresponding to the menu node appears on the right.
  The article is displayed without reloading the entire page.
  That is, after clicking on the menu, only the fragment of the page where the article is located is updated.

**Note.**
Node.I'm studying js.
I have minimal C# experience ASP.NET, MVC.

**create_db-2.sql**

```
CREATE DATABASE socka;

--
-- Структура таблицы `articles`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `articles`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` text,
  `background` text,
  `owner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pos` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `lang` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=275 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;


--
-- Структура таблицы `articles`
--
INSERT INTO `articles` (`id`, `title`, `content`, `background`, `owner`, `pos`, `lang`) VALUES
(1, 'Articles-1', 'Content--Articles-1', NULL, NULL, 0, 1),
(2, 'Articles-1-1', 'Content--Articles-1-1', NULL, 1, 0, 1),
(3, 'Articles-1-2', 'Content--Articles-1-2', NULL, 1, 0, 1),
(4, 'Articles-1-3', 'Content--Articles-1-3', NULL, 1, 0, 1),
(5, 'Articles-1-1-1', 'Content--Articles-1-1-1', NULL, 2, 0, 1),
(6, 'Articles-1-1-2', 'Content--Articles-1-1-2', NULL, 2, 0, 1),
(7, 'Articles-1-1-3', 'Content--Articles-1-1-3', NULL, 2, 0, 1),
(8, 'Articles-2', 'Content--Articles-2', NULL, NULL, 0, 1),
(9, 'Articles-3', 'Content--Articles-3', NULL, NULL, 0, 1),
(10, 'Articles-4', 'Content--Articles-4', NULL, NULL, 0, 1),
(11, 'Articles-5', 'Content--Articles-5', NULL, NULL, 0, 2);
```

**home.controller.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');

exports.getHomePage = (req, res) => {
    let query = "SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY id ASC"; // query database to get all the players

    // execute query
    db.query(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.redirect('/');
        }

        res.render('index.ejs', {
            title: "Welcome to DB",
            articles: result
        });
    });
};
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <!-- Кодировка веб-страницы -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Настройка viewport -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>...</title>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS (jsDelivr CDN) -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Bootstrap Bundle JS (jsDelivr CDN) -->
    <!--
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</head>
<!-- <body> -->
    <body>
        <!-- class="container" -->
        <div class="container">
            
            <!-- div -->
            <div class="border border-success border-3 p-2 vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
                <!-- HEADER  --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- ---->
                <!-- <header class="py-4 text-center text-uppercase fs-4 bg-primary bg-gradient text-white">
                    Header
                    </header> -->
                    
                    <!-- ROW  --- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- --- --- -->
                    <div class="row py-3 flex-grow-1">
                        
                        <!-- LEFT MENU  --- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- -->
                        <div class="col-3 d-flex">
                            <aside class="bg-danger bg-gradient w-100 d-flex justify-content-left align-items-center text-dark fs-5">                                
                                <% if (articles.length > 0) { %>
                                    <ul>
                                        <% articles.forEach((article, index) => { %>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="hidden" class="articles" name="articles[]" value="<%= article.id %>">     
                                            <span>
                                                <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="#"><%=article.title%></a>
                                            </span>                                
                                            <span>
                                                <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="#"><%=article.owner%></a>
                                            </span>                                
                                            <span>
                                                <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="#"><%=article.number%></a>
                                            </span>                                
                                            <span>
                                                <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="#"><%=article.pos%></a>
                                            </span>                                            
                                          
                                        </li>
                                        <%})%>
                                    </ul>
                                <%}%>
                                </ul>
                            </aside>
                        </div>
                        <!-- PLACEHOLDER  --- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- -->
                        <div class="col-9 d-flex">
                            <main class="bg-light bg-gradient w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-dark fs-5 border border-success border-3">
                            Placeholder
                            </main>
                        </div>
                        <!-- RIGHTBAR  --- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- -->
                        <!-- <div class="col-3 d-flex">
                            <aside class="bg-danger bg-gradient w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-white fs-5">
                            Right Bar
                            </aside>
                        </div> -->
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- FOOTER -->
                    <!-- <footer class="py-4 bg-info bg-gradient text-center text-uppercase fs-4 text-white">
                    Footer
                    </footer> -->
                    
                </div>
                
            </div> <!-- .container -->
            
        </body>
        </html>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a specific question, or are you asking people to write your code?

Comment: @robertklep If anyone knows where the ready-made solution is and how to adapt it for my case, then I will not refuse))
**1.** I need to understand how to implement it? What to use? I can't figure out how to approach this issue at all.
**2.** Need to implement recursion?
Where to implement recursion?
Is it possible to implement in `index.ejs`?
Or is it better to make a recursion in `home.controller.js` and form `<ul>`, `<li>` there and pass it to `index.ejs`?
**3.** What is the solution to this problem? 
I am interested in any suggestions, links, search keywords.

Comment: @robertklep For example this solution https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/treeview/treeview-navigation#ex_label
Will it solve my problem?
I need time to figure out how it works...
whether to figure it out or for `node.js` are there more optimal solutions?

Comment: You're asking for opinion-based answers (and/or recommendations for libraries), which is offtopic on StackOverflow.